Chiral condensate in the constructive bosonization
I am studying the constructive bosonization reading a review: Bosonization for beginners – refermionization for experts,arXiv:cond-mat/9805275, and I had a question about the bosonization of the chiral condensate.
The chiral condensate is defined from the Dirac fermion $\psi = (\psi_L, \psi_R)^{\top}$ as
\begin{equation}
\overline{\psi} \psi = \psi_L^{\dagger} \psi_R + \psi_R^{\dagger} \psi_L.
\end{equation}
Using the bosonization identity (Eq. (63) in the review), the first term becomes
\begin{equation}
\psi_L^{\dagger} \psi_R = a^{-1} e^{i(\phi_L - \phi_R)} e^{i(2\pi / L) (N_L + N_R + 1)x} F_L^{\dagger} F_R,
\end{equation}
where $a$ is the UV cutoff, $L$ is the system size, $N_{\eta}$ is the fermion number operator, and $F_{\eta}$ is the Klein factor.
If we naively neglect the Klein factors $F_L, F_R$ and take the limit $L \to \infty$, we find the bosonized form of the chiral condensate to be
\begin{equation}
\overline{\psi} \psi \propto \cos(\phi_L - \phi_R),
\end{equation}
which is the well-known form in the field-theoretical bosonization. However, as emphasized in the review, the Klein factors can not be neglected when the operator does not conserve each fermion number. While the chiral condensate conserves the total fermion number $N = N_L + N_R$, it does not conserve each fermion number. I presume that a careful treatment should reproduce the cosine form in the field-theoretical bosonization. Does anyone have any insights on this point?
